# splitting ground plane

Tags: ground, h-bridge, 3.3v, ground-plane, 24v

I have a 4 layer board, where I have a 3.3V STM32 and some 3.3V components, and also a 24V H bridge to drive a 24V DC motor. The board is supplied with a 24V DC power supply, the 3.3V is created by a regulator on the board. I split the power plane accordingly, like this:

[image]

You can see where the 24V power input is and where the other components are. The yellow is of course the 3.3V and the red is the 24V power plane.

Now my question is regarding the ground plane. Should I "split" it like this (notice that it is not entirely split):

[image]

Or leave it as a whole like this:

[image]

I know that generally speaking it is not a good idea to split the ground plane because of the return paths. But if I don't "split" the plane, then I directly couple the 24V H bridge noise onto the ground pins of the 3.3V electronics, which does not seem to be a good idea either. The motor eats 2A by the way.

So which one would you advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 3rd option, change the layout so a gap in the GND is not required.

The general rule is "low frequency" return current will take route of lowest resistance (typically a direct route) while "high frequency" will take the route of lowest impedance (typically roughly following the trace as this realises the lowest inductance).

With that in mind, and assuming the H-Bridge is directly coupled to the the 24V, you would want that flow to not cross any of the digital signals.

Likewise the 3v3 switcher (assuming switcher), you do not want its return current interfering with the digital signals.

By arranging similar to below you keep the sensitive parts away from potential noise while keeping a contiguous ground plane.

Why a contiguous ground plane? mitigates creating a gap-antenna, now this might be a bit of a remote concern for your present board, but it is worth keeping the concept in your mind because when you create one, they are the bane of EMI

[image]

Answer (score 2):

'Should I split the ground plane' is asking the wrong question. It's rather like asking 'when I drive with my eyes shut, should I steer to the left or the right?'

The answer to the second question is you should open your eyes.

The answer to your first question is you should place the components so that the return currents do not couple into places they shouldn't. Open your eyes to the paths the return currents are going to take.

It's generally better to first assume you do not have a ground plane. Run the return paths as tracks that follow the outward paths. This makes it a lot easier to see where everything is going to flow.

At the end, then by all means flood your ground plane with copper, except for cuts where you want to prevent current flows. If you know where all your return currents are flowing, it will be obvious whether you need cuts, and where they should go.

FWIW, I generally avoid power planes. They are very rarely the answer to a problem, and waste a whole layer that could be used for power and tracking.

You do need a connection between your MCU ground and your H-bridge device ground of course. In the case of your proposed plane split, the MCU to Hbridge signal lines should not cross the split, but follow the unbroken path of the plane.

It would probably result in a tidier layout to put the 24 V supply input below the H bridge, so that the motor current loop is confined to the lower half of the board, and the MCU control signals to the upper part, both being referenced to the Hbridge ground. This leaves the 24/3.3 power supply to place. Leave the 3.3 V regulator where it is to supply the MCU, and run 24 V to it across the Hbridge, perhaps passing through resistors and/or ferrite beads to bolster the regulator's noise rejection. With the currents geographically confined, you don't need a ground plane split.

Crudely like this

[image]

Comment: "The answer to your first question is you should place the components so that the return currents do not couple into places they shouldn't. Open your eyes to the paths the return currents are going to take." Could you perhaps explain in a bit more detail how one would do this? I'm designing a board similar to the OP

Comment: @ChrisD91 It's difficult to teach this sort of thing. But, consider every circuit as being made with discrete traces, then don't get them tangled up. Keep the return path tracking the outward path. Be aware of the 'reference voltage' of each block. Don't let high currents in one part of the circuit board create current flows and so voltage drops between the reference voltage points of sensitive areas. Some boards with low currents and robust logic can be thrown together onto a ground plane, but a ground plane doesn't magically fix badly interacting layout.